# My iron tawa pan is flaking, how do I fix it?

Tags: cast-iron, seasoning-pans, flatbread, indian-cuisine

I don't think my pan is cast iron which is why I am posting this here. I revived my cast iron pan and it performs beautifully. I use the cast iron pan for doas/pancakes.

The iron pan is lighter but defintely made of iron and does not have a non stick coating on it. It is commonly used in india for cooking flatbreads. I bought it at a local shop a few years ago. It looks very similar to [this](https://www.amazon.in/Amicus-Premium-Pure-Iron-Tawa/dp/B07H2HPP12/ref=pd_sbs_79_1/258-5320885-6379536?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07H2HPP12&pd_rd_r=9e06db9e-97af-45b0-a89f-73c9730a7649&pd_rd_w=bsoBU&pd_rd_wg=IoTrL&pf_rd_p=5c023088-3bf1-437a-ba7d-b879da18a58e&pf_rd_r=JK1G2CDMT1QFAG7N7576&psc=1&refRID=JK1G2CDMT1QFAG7N7576).

When I cook rotis/flatbreads on it, it flakes. Little black bits come onto the bread.

My method of cooking is this.

1. Heat pan.
2. Place flatbread on it for a while.
3. Flip it, brush some oil on cooked side.
4. Flip again, brush some oil on other cooked side, keep away.

If I brush oil directly on the pan, it smells weird.

I scrape and wipe the flakes off with a piece of cloth when it gets bad. But yeah, this pan has a huge flaking problem. What's causing it?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have cast iron, forged iron, or some other technology - the methods for seasoning them and maintaining them are the same. So closing as a duplicate of a flaking cast iron pan. If you never seasoned it intentionally, it still has some buildup from cooking, so the advice in the other question still applies.

Comment: As far as I know, what the natives do is scrap,use and repeat :)